# How to install zookeeper as service on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-zookeeper, centos7

I am trying to install zookeeper on CentOS 7 using `yum install zookeeper` or  `yum install zookeeperd` but it throws: `There is no zookeeper package available.`

Comment: You can download e.g. wget http://apache.spd.co.il/zookeeper/current/apache-zookeeper-3.8.2-bin.tar.gz etc https://blog.redbranch.net/2018/04/19/zookeeper-install-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to add the repo that contains zookeeper. You can do this with:

```
yum install https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/redhat/7/x86_64/cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm
```

Afterwards you can install zookeeper normally.

See the documents here:

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_zookeeper_package_install.html
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html

Comment: Cannot open: https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/redhat/7/x86_64/cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm. Skipping.

Answer (score 28):

An alternative answer if you don't want to install a 3rd party repo from cloudera you could use the [Apache Bigtop](http://bigtop.apache.org/) repo. Apache being the actual maintainer of Zookeeper.

As of writing it's [this repo file](https://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/stable/repos/centos7/bigtop.repo) on CentOS 7.

This will let you install Zookeeper by simply running `yum install zookeeper`.

Unfortunately that package does not include a systemd service file so I had to write my own, but that's not very hard.

```
[Unit]
Description=Zookeeper
After=syslog.target

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=zookeeper
TimeoutStartSec=10min
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You can name the file `zookeeper.service`, place it in `/etc/systemd/system/`, and set permissions as `chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/zookeeper.service` (see: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files)